# Using a String to return results from a database

Tags: python

I’m trying to create a python script that will take a string and determine which lines to return from a database table. For instance, if the string is, “Dolphins are a very smart animal”. The python script should search for the term Dolphins and smart and then return the lines “Dolphins are an extremely smart animal”, and “Dolphins are one of the most intelligent animals”. An example rendering of the table is shown below. Any ideas on where to start. I'm currently transitioning from R to Python.

```
Table A 
Animals    Characteristics   Statement
Dolphins     Smart                Dolphins are an extremely smart animal
Dolphins     Smart                Dolphins are one of the most intelligent animals
Bears        Smart                Bears are extremely smart animals
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you research the following things:

- **Stop words**: There key terms in your query are "dolphins", "smart", and "animals". The other terms in the query (e.g. "are", "a") do not help narrow your query against the list of statements. These are "stop words" that can be excluded from your query so that only the key terms are used to search for the relevant statements.
- **Synonym rings**: The words "smart" and "intelligent" are semantically similar. Synonym rings are lists of words that you can use to take a query like "dolphins AND smart" to "dolphins AND (smart OR intelligent)".

If you are working with English statements, [WordNet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/) has a database of synonyms that can be used to generate synonym rings.